# Matlab Set X-axis to display first and last value

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

For my bar graph, I only want to show the first and last value on the x-axis. Is there a way to do that in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, use `xtick([first last])`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do so is:

```
plot(...),xlim([xmin xmax])
```